# Script to search ".exe" & ".msi"

Tags: batch-file

This is my script:
I do not need to search "C:\Program Files" & "C:\Windows" folders. How can I do to skip this directories?

```
@Echo Off
@Echo Scanning In Progress... This Will Take Several Time!! 
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set starttime=%time%

cd\
set Directory=Directory
set Date Created=Date Created
set Date Modified=Date Modified
set Date Accessed=Date Accessed
set FileName=FileName

Echo %Directory%,%Date Created%,%Date Modified%,%Date Accessed%,%FileName% >>c:\users\user\desktop\Result.csv

For /r "c:\" %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") DO (
@Echo %%a
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%b in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "datecreated=%%c  %%d%%e"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%f in ('dir /tw "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "datemodified=%%g  %%h%%i"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%j in ('dir /ta "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "dateaccessed=%%k  %%l%%m"
For /f "tokens=6 delims=] " %%n in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "filename=%%n"

Echo "%%a",!datecreated!,!datemodified!,!dateaccessed!,!filename! >>c:\users\user\desktop\Result.csv 
)
set endtime=%time%

set /a hrs=%endtime:~0,2%
set /a hrs=%hrs%-%starttime:~0,2%

set /a mins=%endtime:~3,2%
set /a mins=%mins%-%starttime:~3,2%

set /a secs=%endtime:~6,2%
set /a secs=%secs%-%starttime:~6,2%

if %secs% lss 0 (
    set /a secs=!secs!+60
    set /a mins=!mins!-1
)
if %mins% lss 0 (
    set /a mins=!mins!+60
    set /a hrs=!hrs!-1
)
if %hrs% lss 0 (
    set /a hrs=!hrs!+24
)
set /a tot=%secs%+%mins%*60+%hrs%*3600

Echo Start = %starttime%
Echo End   = %endtime%
Echo Hours = %hrs%
Echo Minutes = %mins%
Echo Seconds = %secs%
Echo Total = %tot%
Echo Scanning Progress Compeleted!!
Endlocal 
@pause
```

I do not need to search "C:\Program Files" & "C:\Windows" folders. How can I do to skip this directories?

Comment: I do not need to search ".exe" & ".msi" files in "C:\Program Files" & "C:\Windows". How can I do that? Please advise me..

Answer (score 0):

To avoid two fixed folder names, after the the FOR /r statement add:

```
set "d=%%a"
if /i not "!d:~0,17!"=="c:\program files\" if /i not "!d:~0,11!"=="c:\windows\" (
```

At the bottom of the FOR block add an additional closing

```
)
```

Unwanted filenames will be generated by the FOR but will not be processed.

As an example of making the excluded directory list variable, replace the FOR line with:

```
set xd="c:\program files\" c:\windows\ "c:\program files (x86)" %*
For /r "c:\" %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") DO (
set "d=%%a"
for %%x in (%xd%) do if not "!d:%%~x=!"=="!d!" set "d="
if exist d (
```

At the bottom of the FOR block add an additional closing

```
)
```

Files within directories in the %xd% list will not be processed.  Also the caller may specify additional directories not to be processed as command line arguments, eg:

```
myscript "c:\users\all users\" c:\ProgramData\
```

Comment: What does "!d:~0,17!"=="C:\program files\" and "!d:~0,11!"=="C:\windows\" mean??

Comment: Let's said, I wanted to skip "C:\Program Files (x86)" this directory too. What would be the script for it??

Comment: Oh, I think I got it.  As for C:\Program Files (x86)\". Will be "!d:~0,23!"=="C:\program files (x86)\"

Comment: Yes you got it.  I see my answer had unnecessary logic so I simplified it a bit.

Comment: Can this script run on Window NT OS?   set "d=%%a"
if /i not "!d:~0,17!"=="c:\program files\" if /i not "!d:~0,11!"=="c:\windows\" (

Comment: This script set "d=%%a"
if /i not "!d:~0,17!"=="c:\program files\" if /i not "!d:~0,11!"=="c:\windows\" does not work on WinNT OS. Please advise me.

Comment: Sorry can't help you.  NT is a couple decades old; I've never used it and have no access to it.  Perhaps someone who does NT will chime in.

Comment: Hi, it is possible to allow user to choose which directory to skip processing ?

Comment: "!d:~0,17!"=="C:\program files\" - Is to Skip "C:\program files\" processing. Is that a way to allow users to choose which directory to Skip?

Comment: Yes there's probably a way.  It would depend on how the (now variable) set of excluded directories is represented.

Comment: Hi Paul, May I know how can I do that?

Comment: I've added to my original answer to show one way user-specified directories might be skipped.